# BUCLE FOR EN PHP [DUDA]

Tags: php, bucle-for

Estoy empezando con PHP y tengo el siguiente código:

```
if(isset($_POST["codigo"])){
$codigo=$_POST["codigo"];

//$res = substr($codigo, 0,1);
$res1 = substr($codigo, 1,3);
$res2 = substr($codigo, 4,1);

for ($res=substr($codigo, 0,1); $res<3; $res++){
    echo "<p>$res</p>";

        if($res1>3){
            echo "<p>$res1</p>";
        }
}

echo "<p>$res2</p>";
```

Mi misión es recoger de un formulario un código postal introducido por el usuario (Ejemplo: 26428) y ese código debo imprimirlo en otra página dividido en 3 líneas:

Si por ejemplo introduzco 26428 debe aparecerme así en la siguiente página:

2 -> Primera línea = primer dígito

642 -> Segunda línea = tres siguientes dígitos

8 -> Tercera línea = dígito último restante

El problema viene cuando meto un código postal que empieza por 6 o por otro numero que no sea 2, me lo devuelve incorrectamente.
Como puedo modificar mi bucle for para que me acepte cualquier código postal y no solo los que empiecen por 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, no entiendo la estructura de tu bucle `for`, ya que la función `substr` te devuelve un `string` y para un `for`, necesitas un entero (`int`)

Ahora bien, pueden introducir códigos de más de 5 dígitos o de menos y tu script puede tener inconvenientes (aunque hagas la verificación en el frontend, esta puede ser fácilmente evadida), por lo que tendrás que hacer la verificación en el backend también, usando [`strlen`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php)

```php
# Modo de uso: strlen(string: cadenda) : int
# Ejemplo
echo strlen("Hola"); # 4
```

Ahora bien, una vez hecha la verificación, podemos pasar a recién usar [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)

Para obtener el primer dígito, no necesitas esta función, pues puedes acceder fácilmente a este con los corchetes de indexación

Del mismo modo para el último dígito, usando los corchetes y la función `strlen` también

De manera que podemos obtener

```
# Primer dígito
$d1 = $cadena[0];
$d2 = substr($cadena, 1, 3)
$d3 = $cadena[strlen($cadena) - 1];
# La indexación va de 0 a (length - 1)
# Queda restarle a la longitud de la cadena para obtener el último dígito
# De otra manera, obtendremos undefined
```

Ahora simplemente queda integrarlo con `$_POST`

```php
if (isset($_POST["codigo"]) && strlen($_POST["codigo"]) === 5) {
    $cadena = $_POST["codigo"];
    $d1 = $cadena[0];
    $d2 = substr($cadena, 1, 3);
    $d3 = $cadena[strlen($cadena) - 1];
    print("<p>$d1</p><p>$d2</p><p>$d3</p>");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación, he utilizado bucle for porque es lo que me piden en el planteamiento. Mediante un bucle for y substr realizar lo que he expuesto.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer también mediante [`sscanf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sscanf.php)  e `implode()`.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
/*
    Recuperamos con un ternario
*/

$postalCode=(!empty($_POST["codigo"])) && (strlen($_POST["codigo"]) === 5) ? $_POST["codigo"] : NULL;
if ($postalCode) {

    /*
        %1c%3c%1c indica separar la cadena en partes
        %1c primer dígito
        %3c tres siguientes dígitos
        %1c siguiente dígito
    */  
    $parts=sscanf($postalCode,'%1c%3c%1c');
    /*
        Dado que sscanf devuelve un array, podemos usar implode así
    */
    echo implode(PHP_EOL,$parts);
} else {
    echo "El valor no tiene el formato requerido o está vacío";
}
```

**Salida:**

```
2
642
8
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme, me ha quedado claro todo!